# CollectionView not showing when using grouping

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionview

Any idea as to what am I missing when creating a `CollectionView` & `ObservableRangeCollection` grouping list? Currently, nothing showing up.

I am following ref: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MyCoffeeApp/blob/master/MyCoffeeApp/MyCoffeeApp/ViewModels/CoffeeEquipmentViewModel.cs

```
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryListGroup }"
                    IsGrouped="True" 
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged">
        <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Key}"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentView>
                    <Grid Padding="0">
                        <Frame CornerRadius="3" BorderColor="#f2f4f5" HasShadow="True">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Source="icon_about"
                                           WidthRequest="25"  />
                                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center">
                                    <Label VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                FontSize="16" 
                                                Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                </ContentView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

back end code: here I created a list and then putting into the grouping list

```
  ObservableRangeCollection<CategoryModel> CategoryList { get; set; }
 ObservableRangeCollection<Grouping<string, CategoryModel>> CategoryListGroup { get; set; }

   CategoryList = new ObservableRangeCollection<CategoryModel>();
        CategoryList.Add(new CategoryModel { Category = "Cat1", Name = "random text" });
        CategoryList.Add(new CategoryModel { Category = "Cat1", Name = "random text" });
        CategoryList.Add(new CategoryModel { Category = "Cat2", Name = "random Text" });
        CategoryList.Add(new CategoryModel { Category = "Cat2", Name = "random text" });
        CategoryList.Add(new CategoryModel { Category = "Cat3", Name = "random text" });
        CategoryList.Add(new CategoryModel { Category = "Cat3", Name = "random text" });

        CategoryListGroup = new ObservableRangeCollection<Grouping<string, CategoryModel>>();
            CategoryListGroup.Add(new Grouping<string, CategoryModel>("Cat1", CategoryList.Where(c => c.Category == "Cat1")));
            CategoryListGroup.Add(new Grouping<string, CategoryModel>("Cat2", CategoryList.Where(c => c.Category == "Cat2")));
            CategoryListGroup.Add(new Grouping<string, CategoryModel>("Cat3", CategoryList.Where(c => c.Category == "Cat3")));

  BindingContext = this;
```

Comment: `ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryList }"` - `CategoryList` is not the grouped data

Comment: sorry that was a typo when posting this question. i edited it. btw `CategoryList` works fine

Answer (score 0):

found the issue... I had to make my `model class` to `public` & set `ObservableRangeCollection` to `public` as well

```
public ObservableRangeCollection<CategoryModel> CategoryList { get; set; }
 public ObservableRangeCollection<Grouping<string, CategoryModel>> CategoryListGroup { get; set; }

    public class CategoryModel
    {
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```